# Homicide vs Expanded Homicide

Tags: homicide, fbi

The FBI's Uniform Crime Reporting Program has data for [Homicide](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/explorer/national/united-states/crime), and then has data for [Expanded Homicide](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/explorer/national/united-states/shr). What is the difference between these two? For example... when selecting view by race the homicide data says there was a total of 6185 offenders in 2018, whereas the expanded homicide data says there was a total of 16724 offenders in the same year. What are the missing 10000+ offenders from the non expanded homicide report?

Comment: Read the page https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/explorer/national/united-states/shr#about-the-data

Comment: Yes I have read it, can you clarify what it is saying? Thanks. I understand that the expanded has more details of the offenses, but that shouldn't increase the number of recorded offenses, it should just increase the additional data associated with the already recorded offenses... Hopefully this clarifies my confusion.